# dxFileUploader to component, not URL

Tags: angular, devextreme

I started using DevExtreme modules in my Angular app.

I have an dxFileUploader in my component template that needs an "uploadUrl" to upload the file.

In fact, I don't wanna to really upload this file to my backend, but to store it on a local storage key. (yes, I know the limitations of local storage but I will go that way in this case).

Is there any known way to call a Angular function instead of a url on dxFileUploader?

Case not, is there any way I can have an angular component to receive POST requests? So I will put this component as the uploadUrl and then save on local storage.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't want to post anywhere, what you really want is to store the value on the browser storage, so:

On value change

```
dxFileUploader: { onValueChanged: valueChanged }
```

Get the file

```
 $scope.valueChanged = function(e)
{
   //get the value here and store in the localStorage.
}
```

Comment: But does the dxFileUploader stores the value before sending to uploadUrl? The values object where it stores has only attributes of the file (size/modification size), not the content itself.